# Is Surya Namaskar Considered Dynamic Stretching

Tags: running, stretching, yoga

They say do Dynamic Stretching before run. Will train for Couch to 5K.

Is [Surya Namaskar](http://www.artofliving.org/surya-namaskar-sun-salutation12-poses-leaner-you) considered Dynamic Stretching?

Or are there other Dynamic Stretches to do in addition to Surya Namaskar?

[image]

Comment: If you are doing a stretch movement quickly and moving it is considered dynamic, static stretches are the stretches are those that require you to hold yourself in a specific position for ~20 seconds. Looking at those pictures I would say it best qualifies as static

Comment: @muntasiralam Very well then .... will find dynamic stretches

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Surya Namaskar is considered to be dynamic stretching the poses are not held longer than 10 seconds and there is constant movement while stretching. If you are new to the sun salutations, do your first two rounds with cobra pose instead of upward facing dog.

You can include other dynamic stretches into your sun salutations as well to make it more effective for running. Banarasana (runner's lunge) is a great pose to include. Modify it with the back knee down for a deeper stretch in the quad or include a twist as well to warm up the spine further.

There are three different variations of Surya Namaskar (A, B, and C). [This video on the different variations is fairly good.](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=DVH-l9lAaTI)

Once you're comfortable with them, mix them up a bit to suit your stretching needs.  For a good warm up, try doing 2-3 sets of each type.

Answer (score 2):

Surya Namaskar is considered static as well as dynamic.

It becomes static when you are holding any one position in Surya Namaskar for 30 seconds and when you are getting perfection and comfort in that particular position. If you are following fast rounds in surya namaskar before static positions, it does not make your mind to concentrate on body parts. Before dynamism, anyone should aware of what is exact position of hand, neck and leg. Only following this yoga practice for stretching without deep knowledge is not the good way for getting excellent outcomes. Surya Namaskar has huge importance in Indian Country. I am doing Surya Namaskar daily when sun arises (at least 21 rounds). Within 15 minutes I do 33 rounds. But at very initial days I followed it slowly.

In India, there is one 'Sanskrit' language shlok (sentence)--

**"Sthir Sukham Asanam"**

Meaning - The Asana position (yoga position) in which you body feels comfort and concentration (without getting pain) then that is perfection in that position.

After perfection in each step, dynamism can be followed. Fast Surya Namaskar helps in all the way and to all the body parts. It activates and boost your energy for any work. It strengthens your abs muscles, it generates flexibility in your legs and joints. Cobra position generates flexibility in your back. It reduces your tummy fat. It is excellent stretching because it contains 7 asanas (posturse), 12 positions (few asanas are repeated) in each round. It activates each and every body part. It generates cardio strength also. It is good stretching practice as compared to all.